# Renewing iOS Distribution Certificate Early

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, ios-provisioning

So, I got an email from Apple that said:

"This certificate will no longer be valid in 30 days. To create a new certificate, visit Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles in Member Center."

I went ahead and revoked my certificate and issued a new one from within xcode. However, I notice that the new one expires today. Did I just lose a month on my certificate by renewing early?

Update: I think the issue is solved. It looks like it expires 1 year from the previous expiration date even though I paid early.